# Coefficient of $x^k$ of the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^a (1+x)^b}$

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients

Given positive integers $a$ and $b$, I'd like to calculate the coefficient of $x^k$ of the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^a (1+x)^b}$ in closed form.

By expanding the above, it turns out that the coefficient is $\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-i}\binom{i+a-1}{a-1}\binom{k-i+b-1}{b-1}$, but I cannot simplify this expression any further.

Comment: You might want to consider the ways of writing $k=ma+nb$ for non-negative integers $m$ and $n$.  Then consider the parities of the $n$s

Comment: What's the remark "in constant time" for?

Comment: @Raskolnikov It means he wants a closed form for it. Constant time means that the computer does not have to go in a loop which takes more and more time as the number gets bigger.

Comment: I don't think you can get a computation in constant time already for $a = 3, b = 0$ where the coefficient is ${k+1 \choose 2}$. You need to calculate the product of $k+1$ and $k+2$ and it takes time $O(\log k)$ even to read the input $k$! Do you mean a constant number of arithmetic operations?

Comment: I've updated the statement to make it clear.